# Android Application crashes app while using content provider. i.e. Cursor Class

Tags: android

Android Application crashes app while using content provider. i.e. Cursor Class

package com.example.avinash.contentprovider;

```
import android.database.Cursor; 
import android.net.Uri;  
import android.provider.ContactsContract; 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Uri myuri= ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

    String[] proj=new String[]{
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};


    Cursor c=getContentResolver().query(myuri,proj,null,null,null);


  }
}
```

Comment: The [logcat will tell you what reason your app has stopped](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this). Please [edit] your question with it.